# How to fix this Typescript warning

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here I am returning an array for the particular key.

```
type Dictionary<T> = {
  [key: string]: T,
}[];

function pluck<T>(arr: Dictionary<T>, key: string): T[] {
  return arr.map((item) => item[key]);
}

const arr: Dictionary<{ name: string, age: number }> = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 25 }, //Here I am getting this warning Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; age: number; }'.
  { name: "Bob", age: 30 },
  { name: "Charlie", age: 35 },
];

const names: string[] = pluck(arr, "name");
const ages: number[] = pluck(arr, "age");

console.log(ages); // Output: [25, 30, 35]
```

The code is working fine, but I am not able to find the issue. Please help.

Comment: It’s not clear what the problem is. See [ask]

Comment: Your `Dictionary` expects key value pairs as `{ key1: { name: "Alice", age: 25 }, key2:  { name: "Bob", age: 30 }, }` as an array. You're just supplying an array without the key-value pair defined in `Dictionary`.

Comment: Your types are unfortunately almost completely wrong for what you're doing; you don't want `Dictionary`, you just want `Array`, and you want `pluck` to be generic in both the element type `T` of `arr` and the type `K` of `key`.  AngYC's answer is the correct approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it to generic arguments with `extends` instead, with that you can extract the type properly:

```
function pluck<T, K extends keyof T>(arr: Array<T>, key: K): Array<T[K]> {
  return arr.map((item) => item[key]);
}

const arr = [
  { name: 'Alice', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Bob', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Charlie', age: 35 }
];

const names: string[] = pluck(arr, 'name');
const ages: number[] = pluck(arr, 'age');

console.log(names, ages);
```